# Interpolating datetime Index

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame (df) as follow where 'date' is a datetime index (Y-M-D):

df :
                        values
date
2010-01-01             10
2010-01-02             20
2010-01-03         - 30

I want to create a new df with interpolated datetime index as follow:

values
date
2010-01-01 12:00:00       10
2010-01-01 17:00:00       15       # mean value betw. 2010-01-01 and 2010-01-02
2010-01-02 12:00:00       20
2010-01-02 17:00:00      - 5       # mean value betw. 2010-01-02 and 2010-01-03
2010-01-03 12:00:00    -30

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you explain more?  Is necessary manually add rows with `17:00:00` ? Are your data [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes. Initial df.index only contains year-month-date with no time index (i.e., 2010-01-01). Here, 1) I need to add a time index (12:00:00) to each row (i.e., 2010-01-01 12:00:00), then 2) I need to create another row with time index with 17:00:00 for each row in the above 1). Then 3) I need to add value for each new row with mean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need add `12` hours to index first, then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) new indices with `17` and last [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(df.index + pd.Timedelta(12, unit='h'))
idx = (df.index + pd.Timedelta(17, unit='h')).union(df1.index)

df2 = df1.reindex(idx).interpolate()
print (df2)
                     values
date                       
2010-01-01 12:00:00    10.0
2010-01-01 17:00:00    15.0
2010-01-02 12:00:00    20.0
2010-01-02 17:00:00    -5.0
2010-01-03 12:00:00   -30.0
2010-01-03 17:00:00   -30.0
```